# Error when using dplyr::mutate with mapply

Tags: r, dplyr, mapply

I want to use mutate on each of two data frames in a list, adding a column `z = 3` to the first and `z = 4` to the second (and returning a list of two data frames).

```
dfs <- list(data.frame(x = 1), data.frame(y = 2))
mapply(dplyr::mutate, dfs, z = 3:4, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
#> Error in lazyeval::lazy_dots(...): Promise has already been forced
```

What's going wrong for me, and how should I go about doing what I want to do?

Answer (score 2):

Using an anonymous function works:

```
mapply(function(df, z) mutate_(df, z=z), dfs, 3:4, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
#[[1]]
#  x z
#1 1 3
#
#[[2]]
#  y z
#1 2 4
```

Comment: Thanks, that does what I want. Any idea why what I tried is failing?

Comment: Or without anonymous `Map(mutate_, dfs, z = 3:4)`

Comment: @RoryNolan Just changing your original code to use `mutate_` (the "programming friendly" version) works fine. The anonymous function is unnecessary. `mapply(dplyr::mutate_, dfs, z = 3:4, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)`. We could talk about NSE, lazy evaluation, etc as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this with `map2` from the `purrr` package if you want to stay in the `tidyverse`:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

map2(dfs, 3:4, ~ .x %>% mutate(z=.y))
```

> ```
> [[1]]
>   x z
> 1 1 3
>
> [[2]]
>   y z
> 1 2 4
> ```

You can also pipe the list into `map2`:

```
dfs %>% map2(3:4, ~ .x %>% mutate(z=.y))
```